# Put two divs one near the other

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="demand page">
    <div id="crumby-title">
            <div class="page-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="page-title">
                Demand 
            </div>
    </div>   
    <div id="chart" class="demand-chart">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css/less:

```
.rtm {
    .app__header {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15);
    }
    .app__inner-content {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .demand-chart{
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    #crumby-title {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    .page-icon {
        font-size: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 14px 18px;
        background: #e7e7e7;
    }
    .page-title {
        float: left;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 5px 10px 10px 75px;
        height: 55px;
    }
}
```

I tried to do like this in order to show the page-icon and page-title one near the other but how it is done now they are one over the other (the icon is on top of the title)

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "near each other" I am assuming you mean "beside each other".

You can add `flexbox` properties to `#crumby-title`. Then remove `position` and `float` properties from `.page-icon` and `page-title`. You can also remove `height` from `.page-title`

```css
.app__header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15);
}

.app__inner-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.demand-chart {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#crumby-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.page-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 18px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

.page-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 5px 10px 10px 75px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="demand page">
  <div id="crumby-title">
    <div class="page-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="page-title">
      Demand
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chart" class="demand-chart">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `float:left` to `.page-icon` instead of `position:absolute` and add `<div class="clear"></div>` after `page-title`.

```css
.app__header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15);
}
.app__inner-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.demand-chart{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#crumby-title {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;    
}
.page-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 18px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}
.page-title {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 5px 10px 10px 75px;
  height: 55px;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="demand page">
  <div id="crumby-title">
    <div class="page-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="page-title">
        Demand 
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>   
  <div id="chart" class="demand-chart">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to show u another version of ankita pantel's put them in a table and add padding-top to Demand

```css
    .app__header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15);
}
.app__inner-content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.demand-chart{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#crumby-title {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.page-icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 14px 18px;
    background: #e7e7e7;
}
.page-title {
    padding-top: 30px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 5px 10px 10px 75px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="demand page">
    <div id="crumby-title">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="page-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="page-title">
                Demand 
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>   
    <div id="chart" class="demand-chart">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the cool kids are using flex box.

display:flex; flex-direction:row; makes the child items stack in a row. (flex-direction:row is default so you can skip that)

```
#crumby-title {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

---

then you can (if you want) center the text with

```
.page-title {
    ....
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssaa46eL/1/)

Comment: @ovokuro, yes I know, and I say so in the answer. I put it there because I think it helps someone who is seeing flex box for the first time understanding how it works.